# Uniqueness of Singular Values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Given a matrix A, one inductively constructs (and thus proving its very existence) the singular value decomposition as follows: take $ \sigma_{1}=||A||_{2} $, and consider a couple of vectors such that 
\begin{equation}
 A\textbf{v}_{1} = \sigma_{1} \textbf{u}_{1}
 \end{equation}
Now extend to two orhogonal bases and write down the first step:
\begin{equation}
  U_{1}^{T} A V_{1} = S = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \sigma_{1} & \textbf{0}^{T} \\ 
 \textbf{0} & A_{1}
 \end{bmatrix} 
 \end{equation} 
Now take $A_{1}$, and repeat inductively, costructing
\begin{equation}
U_{2}^{T} A_{1} V_{2} = S_{2} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
 \sigma_{2} & \textbf{0}^{T} \\ 
 \textbf{0} & A_{2}
 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
which gives rise to second singular value, by selecting $\sigma_{2}=||A_{1}||$.

> My question is: suppose we choose another couple of extensions to
>   orthogonal bases, call them $\hat{U_{1}},\hat{V_{1}}$. Doing so, we'll
>   obtain **another** matrix $\hat{A_{1}}$: who guarantees this
>   $\hat{A_{1}}$ has the same norm of ${A_{1}}$, thus giving the same
>   second singular value $\sigma_{2}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if the columns of $U$ and $\hat{U}$ span the same subspace, then $\hat{U}=UM$ for some nonsingular $M$. If the columns of both $U$ and $\hat{U}$ are orthonormal, the matrix $M$ is orthogonal because $I=\hat{U}^T\hat{U}=M^TU^TUM=M^TM$.

So, if $U_1=[u_1,\tilde{U}_1]$ and $\hat{U}_1=[u_1,\tilde{\hat{U_1}}]$, then $\hat{U}_1=[u_1,\tilde{U}_1]M$ for some orthogonal matrix $$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\tilde{M}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Similarly, $\hat{V}_1=V_1N$ for an orthogonal matrix 
$$N=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&\tilde{N}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Therefore,
$$
\hat{A}_1=\tilde{\hat{U}}_1^TA\tilde{\hat{V}}_1=M^T\tilde{U}_1^TA\tilde{V}_1N=\tilde{M}^TA_1\tilde{N}.
$$

The matrices $A_1$ and $\hat{A}_1$ have *the same 2-norm* since the 2-norm is orthogonally invariant, that is, $\|A_1\|=\|PA_1Q\|$ for any square orthogonal matrices $P$ and $Q$ because $\|PA_1Q\|^2=\rho((PA_1Q)^T(PA_1Q))=\rho(Q^TA_1^TA_1Q)=\rho(A_1^TA_1)=\|A_1\|^2$ and hence in the induction step the $\sigma_2$ is same no matter what orthonormal bases of the orthogonal complements of $u_1$ and $v_1$ you choose.

Comment: Very clear and detailed, thanks. With $\rho(-)$ you are indicating the spectral radus?

Comment: And why $\hat{U}=UM$ and not $\hat{U}=M^T UM$? After all, $\hat{U}$ and $U$ should be similar via the orthogonal change of basis operated by $M$..

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, $\rho$ is the spectral radius.

Comment: @MadHatter This is maybe a misunderstanding. $U$ and $\hat{U}$ contain bases of some subspace in their columns, it means $U$ and $\hat{U}$ are, say, $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ ($m\geq n$) such that $\mathrm{Im}(U)=\mathrm{Im}(\hat{U})$. Since their image is equal, there exists a nonsingular $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\hat{U}=UM$. It is exactly a change of basis, the basis contained in the columns of $U$.

Comment: @MadHatter ...and that $M$ is in addition orthogonal if the columns of both $U$ and $\hat{U}$ are orthonormal, that is, if you change one orthonormal basis into another orthonormal basis, the transformation matrix is orthogonal too.

Comment: Ok, so we would have used $\hat{U}=M^T U M$, **IF** we did select the same basis for the domain, but here we are selecting two different bases on the very purpose. Thank you again, perfectly clear!

Comment: No no, in the given context this product even would not make sense since $M$ is square and $U$'s are rectangular. Also, $\hat{U}$ defined in such a way would not span the same space as $U$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgotten the possible rectangularness of $U$s...

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\widehat U_1^T U_1 \pmatrix{\sigma_1&0^T\\0&A_1}V_1^T\widehat V_1
=
\pmatrix{\sigma_1&0^T\\0&\widehat  A_1}
$$
Break the unitary matrices into block matrices to see that $\widehat A_1 = U A_1 V^T$ for unitary matrices $U,V$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in a struggle about what answer to accept. Pavel gave a bit more detailed explanation, but you answered first.

Comment: @MadHatter: accept Pavel's; when people search for this question, his is the answer that people will want to see first.

Comment: Many thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help${}{}$